# Remove "Pending" group member via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api

In a Google Apps for Education domain, I can approve a "pending" user in a group by setting their role to "member", also and I can remove a user with the role of "member" with the code below:

```
member = AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupKey, memberKey);
```

But the same code does not work for a user with a role of "PENDING".

Is there a way to reject/remove an invite/pending user via Google Apps Directory Script?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this use-case was left out of the Directory API (therefore this is not really an Apps Script issue).

You should report this issue here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/wiki/IssuesTab?tm=3

Comment: Thanks I will. I found that the hackish workaround was to add as member, then remove, but I'd rather something supported in the API

Comment: Yes, I've thought of that solution, but didn't had the courage to suggest it, given how "hackish" it is. You're giving authorization to a user you clearly want to just deny. What if your script fails in between calls?